# sum of an infinite series in octave

Tags: math, octave, inf

Just started acquaintance with Octave. Trying to calculate the sum of an infinite series. Math is bad, can anyone help? In the code for x I took one.

[row formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8oZY.png)

[image]

```
sum((-1)^([1:inf]+2)/factorial([1:inf])*1^[1:inf]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, the formula is

```
exp(-1/x)-1
```

which can derived from Taylor expansion.

---

**Symbolic verification**

```
pkg load symbolic
syms x n
simplify(symsum((-1/x).^n./(factorial(n)),n,1,inf))
```

which gives

```
>> simplify(symsum((-1/x).^n./(factorial(n)),n,1,inf))
ans = (sym)

        -1
        ---
         x
  -1 + e
```

---

**Numeric verification**

```
n = 20;
x = 2;
```

such that

```
>> sum((-1/x).^(1:n)./(factorial(1:n)))
ans = -0.39347
>> exp(-1/x)-1
ans = -0.39347
```